# How to change state for the users with the user_id (with that error)

Tags: python, asynchronous, bots, telegram, aiogram

I found this code:

```
state = dp.current_state(chat=chat_id, user=user_id)
await state.set_state(User.accepted)
```

But when I run it, I have that error:
**TypeError: Dispatcher.current_state() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given**

It should work like in another question on stackoverflow, but it doesn't.
Also i couldn't change states with the set_state function, so i used `ClassWithStates.state_name.set()`